# Where to put own class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 2.1. Actually I am used to symfony 1.4. I do have a file in symfony 1.4 under lib/DataFormatChecker.php. There are global functions, e.g. emailchecker. Where is the best way to put this file and how can I use it in symfony 2.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost the same question has been discussed here:

[Where to store simple 3rd party class in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994212/where-to-store-simple-3rd-party-class-in-symfony2)

You find the documentation from Symfony here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html

Please note that there already is a validator component https://github.com/symfony/Validator that ships with Symfony2 ;)